# Why is output from 'git diff' different than 'git show'?

Tags: git

I expected `git show <commit>` and `git diff <commit>^ <commit>` to show the all changes that took place in a given commit, but I see that their list of changes differs. (See example below.) What's the correct understanding of their function, then?

Yes, I've read the man pages

git show

```
For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents the
   merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree --cc.
```

git diff

```
git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

---

### E.g.

```
$ MY_COMMIT=7c95d118c9837f801f4e314732c593e25feba3b1
```

#### `git show` and its output:

```
$ git show --name-only $MY_COMMIT
commit 7c95d118c9837f801f4e314732c593e25feba3b1
Merge: 5f308b4 9ef9bd7
Author: Me <quinesquines@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 23 14:14:58 2015 -0700

    Merge branch 'develop' of github.com:pic-development/dataraptor into develop

    Conflicts:
        app/controllers/application_controller.rb
        app/controllers/usage/staff_assignment_controller.rb
        app/views/crm/connections/_show.html.erb
        app/views/crm/task_builders/_task_builders.html.haml
        spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb
        spec/controllers/crm/connections_controller_spec.rb

app/controllers/application_controller.rb
app/controllers/usage/staff_assignment_controller.rb
app/views/crm/connections/_show.html.erb
```

#### `git diff` and its output:

```
$ git diff --name-only $MY_COMMIT^ $MY_COMMIT
app/assets/javascripts/application/quoting/ng-new-quote.js
app/assets/stylesheets/application-layout.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
app/controllers/application_controller.rb
app/controllers/crm/connections_controller.rb
app/controllers/usage/staff_assignment_controller.rb
app/models/crm/connection.rb
app/models/usage/permissions.rb
app/views/crm/connections/_show.html.erb
app/views/crm/task_builders/_task_builder.html.erb
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
app/views/marketing/campaigns/_index.html.haml
app/views/marketing/campaigns/_task_builders.html.haml
app/views/shared/tab/_agency_management.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_contracts.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_help.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_marketing.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_my_account.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_reporting.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_sales_tools.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_system_management.html.erb
app/views/shared/tab/_underwriting_suitability.html.erb
app/views/usage/agent_field_sets/_new_submission_option.html.erb
app/views/usage/users/_personal.html.erb
vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-combined.min.css
vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css
vendor/assets/stylesheets/pixel-admin.css
vendor/assets/stylesheets/themes.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are displaying the diff of a merge commit**.

Consider an example with the following commits (F being the newest one), and you're doing a `git show F` and a `git diff F^ F` (which is effectively a `git diff C F`).

```
A--B--C--F
 \      /
  D----E
```

1. `git show` shows **only the files that were changed in the merge commit itself**. This may include files that had merge conflicts which were manually fixed. It will **not** show files that were modified in one of the merged branches (so B,C or D,E) and could be merged cleanly. To quote the man page (emphasis mine):

   > For commits [git show] shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by git diff-tree --cc.
   >
   > [git diff-tree --cc] further compresses the patch output by **omitting uninteresting hunks** whose the contents in the parents have only two variants and the merge result **picks one of them without modification**.
2. `git diff <commit>^ <commit>` shows the diff of the **merge commit's first parent and the merge commit**. Since the merge commit contains all changes from both the first and second parent, you're effectively shown the diff of **the entire branch** (so in my example, commit D and E) that was merged in that commit.

Answer (score 0):

By default, for a merge commit, `git show` produces (as the documentation says) a "combined diff".  Using `git diff` directly with only two of the three or more commits involved<sup>1</sup> produces a regular (non-combined) diff.

The [documentation on combined diffs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format) is a bit buried, and for some reason this sentence:

> Note that combined diff lists only files which were modified from all
>          parents.

is in another section entirely.  And, the section linked here refers to `git diff` when you can't tell `git diff` to look at all of the merge's parents simultaneously (you have to use `git diff-tree` or `git show` for that).

---

<sup>1</sup>A merge commit is one with at least two parents, so the three or more commits here are the commit you're `git show`-ing, its first parent (`$MY_COMMIT^1`), its second parent (`$MY_COMMIT^2`), and any additional parents (`$MY_COMMIT^3`, etc., for "octopus merges").